# Jquery select element error

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with element selection, i have a form and i want to run `each` function for each form `select` box, here is my code:

```
$("#profile_form select").each(function(i){
    var seen = {};
    $(this + 'option').each(function() {
        var txt = $(this).text();
        if (seen[txt])
            $(this).remove();
        else
            seen[txt] = true;
    });
});
```

Now my problem is with `$(this + 'option')` part, if i try to select only select menu it works fine, but i need to select `option` and if i do that i get:

`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLSelectElement]option`

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 $('option', this).each(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(this + "option")` tries to add a string to a DOM element, which is probably not what you want. You might be looking for:

```
$(this).find("option")
```

Or, alternatively:

```
$("option", this)
```